# Dealing with "vw" units in CSS

Tags: css, sass

I have a margin variable in SASS like:

```
$space-xxl: 8vw;
```

I'm using it with elements like

```
.element {
    margin-bottom: $space-xxl;
}
```

This works fine because the margin depends on the screen width. I need a fallback for older browsers, is this the best way to do it?

```
$space-xxl: 8em;
$space-xxl: 8vw;
```

Comment: Do you really need fallback ? http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, I think the fallback needs to be in the element itself, because SASS variables will not be read by the browser after you compile them.

```
.element {
    margin-bottom: 8em;
    margin-bottom: $space-xxl;
}
```

Comment: You are so right *bang head to desk.